# Can I run VirtualBox with Bridged adapters on EC2 and GCE

Tags: amazon-ec2, virtualization, virtualbox, google-compute-engine

I have a Ubuntu 14.04 host on GCE and I want to run a VirtualBox VM on it. The guest is also running Ubuntu 14.04. I want the VM to be visible to other machines in my VPC and bridged adapter seems to be the right way. But, the guest is unable to get the IP address from dhcp and remains stuck there till it times-out. Is there a way I can get the bridged adapter working on GCE or EC2 and make the guest  visible outside the host?

Comment: This makes no sense to me. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: @joeqwerty that's because we get the VM's from clients for testing. And there could be many more reasons why someone may want to do this.

Comment: I don't think anybody else really wants to do this. Why don't you install VirtualBox locally? Alternatively, you could import the customer image to AWS and launch it in it's own EC2 instance. - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/UsingVirtualMachinesinAmazonEC2.html

Comment: That's what we may have to do if the current approach doesn't work out. We do not want to be creating hundreds/thousands of ami's, something that may happen as we receive multiple updates to the VM's from every customer.

Comment: And can't run it locally because these will be used by multiple automated tests running through jenkins.

Comment: AWS' DHCP servers aren't going to hand out IP addresses for random requests.  They *want* you to run more AWS instances, it's how they make money.

Answer (score 1):

Running 'nested' virtual systems (VM's inside VM's) is typically not going to be a good idea for **MANY** reasons, but it can be done under very specific circumstances. I recommend reading this VMware Community post: https://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-8970 While old (and VMware specific), it describes the major issues you encounter when trying to nest VM's and gives some detail about the limitations of this type of setup.

In regards to your networking issues, that will depend on your environment. You don't provide any information about what troubleshooting steps you have taken, which makes it very difficult to help.

Edit: Found this question which is very similar [Anybody get Xen/KVM/Virtualbox/VMWare/Hyper-V running on an EC2 instance?](https://serverfault.com/questions/229930/anybody-get-xen-kvm-virtualbox-vmware-hyper-v-running-on-an-ec2-instance)